# ¿Como descomprimo un archivo tar.gz y que me gener el config.m4?

Tags: php, java, linux, centos, backend

necesito una ayudota y es que estoy haciendo la instalacion de PHP/JavaBridge en un servidor web. Ya tengo el java y el php instalados. Estoy siguiente éste tutorial : http://www.indianwebportal.com/php-java-bridge-plesk

El problema es que cuando llego a la parte de la instalación me encuentro con el detalle de que aparentemente el enlace para descargar el archivo está obsoleto, se cayó el servidor, tumbaron el archivo o que se yo. Intentando suplir dicho archivo, descargué VARIOS archivos de estos. tanto en tar.gz como en rpm y nada. Al descomprimir el tar.gz no me crea el archivo config.m4 que necesita el PHPIZE para preparar la instalacion, y el rpm tampoco lo descomprime. Todos los archivos los he descargado de acá: https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/

El servidor corre en Centos6 y tiene php5.6

El error que me muestra al ejecutar el phpize es:

> Cannot find config.m4.
>   Make sure that you run '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

En serio les agradezco su ayuda infinitamente. Estaré atento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo no viene por defecto.

Intenta esta secuencia:

```
./configure
phpize
make
make install
```

Comment: Me dice esto:  ./configure: No such file or directory